# kobuki_ftdi create_udev_rules not found

Tags: turtlebot, kobuki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I received mu turtlebot with Kobuki and I followed the ROS (Groovy) tutorial for installing Turtlebot and Kobuki
There is a problem with this command

rosrun kobuki_ftdi create_udev_rules

Actually there is no "create_udev_rules" node in the package kabuki_ftdi.
So the command does not work. There are other nodes such as find_device, flasher, ftdi_kobuki, … But not create_udev_rules.
Is there any new process that makes the rules?

I did the following command
roscd kobuki_ftdi
make udev
That I found in installation tutorial
And it make Kobuki appears as /dev/kobuki. But still when I run get_serial_number, I get this output

1 device found
Something went wrong. Did you run with sudo?

When I try rosrun with sudo, it does not accept to execute rosrun with sudo.

When I run minimal launch, it works but gives a problem with the battery.

I hope you can help in fixing this issue.

Thanks
Anis

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55599/kobuki_ftdi-create_udev_rules--not-found/) by [Anis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4199/anis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 253 on 2013-02-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2013-02-24**:
create_udev_rules  is still in ros-shadow-fixed awaiting a push into the ros repo. Just running 'make udev' will work in the interim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sudo does not work with rosrun (or any ros command) because it does not carry across all the ros environment variables. Bad idea anyway, as it saves all your logs and other temporaries as root.

Just try calling it directly with sudo (i.e. without ros) should work.

Having said that, we just catkinized kobuki, so once that deb reaches ros public repo, that binary will be in `/opt/ros/groovy/lib/kobuki_ftdi`. We'll get that moved into `/opt/ros/groovy/bin` so it's easier to find and run and update the wiki instructions this week.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2013-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0